# WebsitePanel 2 totally NOT working on Windows Server 2012 on Azure

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012, azure, iis-8

I’m having many troubles installing WebSitePanel on an Azure Virtual Machine, with Windows Server 2012. I followed the steps in http://www.websitepanel.net/documentation/deployment-guide/server-configuration/preparing-windows-server-2008-r2-for-websitepanel-installation/ and installed everything I needed.

Then, I installed the WebSitePanel Standalone Server package with the installer. I opened the endpoint for the port 9002 on Windows Azure; so I pointed my browser to myhostname.cloudapp.net (note: in Azure you don’t have a static IP address, instead you have an hostname like [hostname].cloudapp.net). So, loading myhostname.cloudapp.net:9002 fails, and any browser shows something like “Unable to load page”.

Notice: if I try to load the WebSitePanel Portal directly on the server, I get an error HTTP 400 Bad Request.

How come? IIS works perfectly on the server, in fact the default website runs without problems on port 80.

Answer (score 0):

the cp and rest of management websites will work only with the fqdn that you declared upon installing WSP, for example when you installed it if you declared cp.example.org then your WSP will respond only to cp.example.org:9001 otherwise you`ll receive a bad request error.

hope it helps